# Accuracy is not improving further

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am using pre-trained GoogLeNet and then fine tuned it on my dataset for classifying 11 classes. I tried the following configurations with different `base_learning rate`, but the `accuracy` is not improving further.

1. I used pre-trained GoogLeNet model and then doing the fine-tuning on last 10 layers and on the first 3 layers with the base learning rate 0.01 and maximum iterations to 50K, but this configuration doesn't give the accuracy better than 75%.
2. I used pre-trained GoogLeNet model and then doing the fine-tuning on last 2 layers with the base learning rate 0.01 and maximum iterations to 50K, but this configuration doesn't give the accuracy better than 71%.
3. I used pre-trained GoogLeNet model and then doing the fine-tuning on last 6 layers with the base learning rate 0.001 and maximum iterations to 50K, but this configuration doesn't give the accuracy better than 85%.

Can anybody tell me, what are the other methods or parameters which I can change to improve the accuracy?

Comment: How about changing the dataset?

Comment: First of all, are you correctly performing model selection + performance estimation? Just trying different hyperparameters and selecting the one with the highest performance leads to overfitting. Second, as already mentioned by @AshutoshSingla, it may not be possible to get a better performance with the specific dataset.

Comment: Have you been babysitting your learning process? Maybe you should stop learning earlier? Have you tried different optimizer - like RMSPROP or ADAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use other optimisers such as ADADELTA, ADAM, and RMSPROP. In your `solver.prototxt` you can set this parameter by writing this command `type: "RMSProp"`

For RMSPROP, you can modify the parameters as mentioned [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver_rmsprop.prototxt).